# I am new to strapi Please how to send an email after the user register, I need him after register he receives an email verification

Tags: reactjs, authentication, strapi, email-validation

I am using strapi v4 and i want when the user register he receives an email verification

after i Enable email confirmation the registeration form dosent work

Answer (score 0):

such questions is better to ask on https://forum.strapi.io/ or on strapi community discord. The stack overflow is more of a code technical question, `e.g. this function does not i would expect it to be doing`.

so the basic steps are following:

1. setup URL in `.env`

```
...
URL=http://localhost:1337
```

`http://localhost:1337` this should be your strapi actual url
if you don't have .env create it in root of your project

2. make sure the url set in config/server.js
   `/config/server.js`

```
module.exports = ({env}) => {
  ...
  url: env("URL", "http://localhost:1337"),
}
```

3. To actually send an email, you need an email plugin:
   https://market.strapi.io/providers/@strapi-provider-email-nodemailer

`yarn add @strapi/provider-email-nodemailer`

after it's installed create file
`config/plugins.js`
with following contents:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  email: {
    config: {
      provider: 'nodemailer',
      providerOptions: {
        host: env('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.example.com'),
        port: env('SMTP_PORT', 587),
        auth: {
          user: env('SMTP_USERNAME'),
          pass: env('SMTP_PASSWORD'),
        },
        // ... any custom nodemailer options
      },
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: 'hello@example.com',
        defaultReplyTo: 'hello@example.com',
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

in your .env (step 1) add following configurations:
`.env`

```
SMTP_HOST=smtp.example.com
SMTP_PORT=587
SMTP_USERNAME=myEmailUsername
SMTP_PASSWORD=myEmailPassword
```

also don't forget to set your email address to this two fileds:

```
defaultFrom: 'hello@example.com',
defaultReplyTo: 'hello@example.com',
```

5. then i've recommend doing `yarn build`
   `yarn develop`

if all is good, you should be able to send test email:
[image]

docs https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#email-validation

6. then go to `Email Templates` and setup Shipper email with exact one you are using
7. then in `Advanced settings` you need to setup `Redirection url`

Then it should work ;)